# Can't change data range on r.scale in qgis

Tags: qgis, raster, grass-gis

I'm trying to rescale a raster to values of 0-1 in order to do a multicriteria analysis in QGIS. I have a raster with integer values from 0-18. However, when I come to try and change the data input range, it wont let me move it past 1.

Any ideas on why this might be happening?

[image: r.rescale from grass GIS]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to follow-up on how I fixed this:

1) it's a matter of data-types in Q; for some reason when you use the field calculator to create a column in the attribute table it doesn't read it as of type integer / float / boolean. You need to create an empty column first specifying the type before adding data via the field calculator.

2) The Saga 'raster normaliser' from the processing toolbox is quicker and doesn't have these issues.